# Javascript mouse events on overlaid/covered/stacked elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to catch the mouse event for an element that is positioned under an other element.

Here is a example of what I have : http://jsfiddle.net/KVLkp/13/

Now what I want is that blue square has yellow borders when mouse is over red square.

The important things are :

- they are images. So there is no way to embed one element in the
  other.
- this is an easy example, but in reality there are many img. So the
  search of hovered elements by coordinate calculations is not my
  solution (I've already found this answer)
- There is no link between the two images except that the mouse is over them all

Thank you for your help

Edit:
I've written a more complete example of my general case :
- img order in DOM is not fixed and can be changed on live
- top and bottom image has various size and position

Thanks to all of you!

Comment: Seeing as you've anticipated the reasonable workarounds, I'm not sure your request can really be fulfilled. Hover bubbles DOM-wise, not arbitrarily positioning-wise. Are you absolutely sure about your premises? For instance: sure, you can't embed one image in another, but do they *have* to be images? Could they just as well be `DIV` elements with background images?

Comment: Here's one way that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/KVLkp/17/ (though perhaps it fails the "no link between the two images" criterion).

Comment: @DavidHedlund They do have to be images because multiple images will be displayed with (quite like) random position, various size, and because I don't want to overflow the dom (my reality is that I can have 4000 images)

Comment: @nnnnnn Nice solution... that would be useful, not for my real thing. I forgot to say that there might be many img under one single image.
Thank a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of the following:

```
<style>
img.hover {
    border-color : yellow;
}​
</style>
<script>
$('img').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}).mouseleave(function (e) {
    var next = e.relatedTarget;
    if (next.tagName.toUpperCase()!="IMG"
                 || $(next).hasClass("hover"))
       $(this).removeClass("hover");
});
</script>
```

Rather than setting the colour of the border directly I've defined a class called "hover" that sets the colour, so that I can easily test whether a given element has the border without hard-coding colours everywhere, and then I've made use of the `event.relatedTarget` property to see where the mouse is going when it leaves.

The "hover" class is only removed if the element the mouse is going to is not an image or is an image that already has the hover class. Seems to work pretty well in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KVLkp/18/, but it won't work if two images are side-by-side with no gap between them or if the image on top isn't completely "contained" (in a coordinate sense) by the img it overlaps - I decided to go ahead and post it anyway because I hope that seeing `event.relatedTarget` in the demo will give you enough of a start to come up with something to fit your real situation.

(Note: "hover" is a bad name for a class given CSS already has the `:hover` pseudo-class, but by the time I remembered I couldn't be bothered changing it in the fiddle and here.)

Comment: You really got it! I think relatedTarget is my mystic method! Thank you! I tried it with my new example (you couldn't know it). It still have some buggy things, but I'll be manage to handle it! thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/KVLkp/20/

Comment: You're welcome. Like I said, I hope it gets you on the right track even though there are cases where my code doesn't work as is. (Sorry, I don't have time now to look at it any more tonight.)

Comment: I accept this answer. But I didn't see that relatedTarget was the target element the mouse just left. And this is not exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicating things more than you have to. Just keep it simple put your events on the inner square and the outer square, but don't use "this" use the get the outer square by id e.g. $('#bluesqure') and then just do your work as if the hover was on the blue square.

I don't know if this would be a possible solution in your real world scenario.

Comment: It won't be possible because when mouse is over red square, I have no idea of which blue square to handle. I mean that I have 100 red squares and 100 blue ones with random coordinates.