# How to enable javascript mouse events on overlapping html elements?

Tags: javascript

This probably cannot be done, but I have a fixed-position div on top of inline html in the page body. The inline html has clickable elements, and the fixed div has a hover event.

The fixed element is an empty div, so it is invisible.

Currently, the fixed element is blocking click events on the item under it.

Is it possible?

This solution is too complicated
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9616491/209942

Possible solution?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The fixed element should not be prevent the clicks from the item under it unless you are stopping the event propagation.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pv0mygz5/
-- it demonstrates that without event.stopPropagation the event should be intercepted by the listener on the span element.

```
$('#click-me').on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('click triggered');
});

$('.box').on('mouseover', function (e) {
    //don't stop event from bubbling
    console.log('hover triggered');
});
```

Could you also include a code snippet that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Not sure that's the OP's issue. The span is in the div and events are propagating up the DOM, perfectly normal. The issue is a block element with position absolute sitting over an element that isn't an ancestor, so events bubble up through the covering element and it's ancestors, which don't include the underlying element, so it can't get the mouse events.  See Julien Grégoire's answer

Comment: Interesting, that is much more of a problem than I interpreted it to be. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: i realized i just want all events on both layers. also seeking non-jquery solution. thx!

Answer (score 0):

although IE10 doesn't support it you can use

```
pointer-events: none;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/XxkSC/light/

In this fiddle you can see a drop down being covered with other elements, the other elements has pointer-events: none so you can click on the arrow down button and the click actually goes to the select element itself.

BR,
Saar

Comment: if pointer-events: none; prevents all events on that layer, it won't do. i actually want all events on both layers

Comment: I don't understand why in your scenario this would be possible, I can think of a way around it using x.y coordinates of the click event - find out if there is an element under the top div in that location (screenX,Y or pageX.Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `z-index`. Depending on your layout it may not be a solution, but if your front `div` is invisible, then it shouldn't create unwanted effect. Like this for example:

```js
document.querySelector('#under').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.style.color = "blue";
});

document.querySelector('#notunder').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.target.style.color = "blue";
});
```

```css
#fix {
  width: 60px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#under {
  display: inline;
}
#fixnozindex {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 75px;
  top: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#notunder {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="fix"></div>
<div id="under">Clickable</div>
<div id="fixnozindex"></div>
<div id="notunder">Not clickable</div>
```